# How do you define global variables so all classes can access/edit them?

Tags: c++, header, global

I am writing a program that has quite a few global variables that need to be accessed and modified by multiple classes. Currently I pass them into objects when they are needed however this is now becoming very complex (and i assume memory intensive as i am passing textures), therefore I am trying to define them once so everything can access them. I am unsure how to define them in this way.

I have created a header file that defines the variables and am including it in all of the other class header files (see below). However as some global variables are objects of classes that global.h is included in I believe I am creating an infinite loop.

My apologies for the lack of knowledge on my part, I have attempted to work through Forward Declarations and Singletons but have had no luck.

```
//This file (global.h) is included by every other class header file 
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

#include "component.h" //component.h also calls global.h

//Viewport Controllers.
extern float viewportX = 0;
extern float viewportY = 0;
extern float viewportZ = 0;
extern float displaySize = 50;
extern float scale = 1;

extern component = component();

#endif
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing I can think of is to create a separate class, and define all your constants as static const variables. You can include this file in all other files where you want to access it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare a global variable that could be used in the entire program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029272/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-that-could-be-used-in-the-entire-program)

Comment: You should reconsider.  Having a lot of mutable global variables can be very problematic.  Try grouping your individual variables into classes so you don't have to pass as many individual variables.  For example, you could have a `ViewportControllers` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating a class called statics. There you can declare constants, readonly vars and methods, which mostly are independent of objects invoking them. Then you have an encapaulation, restricted access to mutability and widespread usage of global global vars.
If You want to have multiple vars being also changed by various classes, then you should create accessors and/or mutators. Keep in mind to be carefull, which class changes what of those static scoped variables in this static class.
Another option would be to use shared memory, but i think,that is beyond of the scope of Your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You define all the global variables in one .cpp file and whenever you have to use them in other file, declare them in that file by qualifying with the `extern` keyword.