# Global Varibles with using namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, global-variables

i have to use my varibles in entire project. I have just defined two string varibles in a namespace and reference this header in main.cpp.

Here App.h and App.cpp:

App.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace App
{
    extern string FingerPrint;
    extern string FingerPrintID;
}
```

App.cpp

```
#include "App.h"

using namespace std;

string FingerPrint = "";
string FingerPrintID = "";
```

And i'm trying to use this varibles in main.cpp like this:

main.cpp

```
#include "App.h"
#include "Helper.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    App::FingerPrint = Helper().GetFingerPrint();
    App::FingerPrintID  = Helper().GetFingerPrintID();

    cout<<"FingerPrintID: "<<App::FingerPrintID<<endl;
    cout<<"FingerPrint: "<<App::FingerPrint<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When i compile this code i get this errors:

> CMakeFiles/HardwareService.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
>   /home/debian/Development/clion-workspace/app/main.cpp:19: undefined
>   reference to`App::FingerPrint'
>   /home/debian/Development/clion-workspace/app/main.cpp:20: undefined
>   reference to `App::FingerPrintID'
>   /home/debian/Development/clion-workspace/app/main.cpp:23: undefined
>   reference to`App::FingerPrintID'
>   /home/debian/Development/clion-workspace/app/main.cpp:24: undefined
>   reference to `App::FingerPrint'

But if i dont use namespace and use this varibles without 'App::', it works.
Like this:

App.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern string FingerPrint;
extern string FingerPrintID;
```

App.cpp

```
#include "App.h"

using namespace std;

string FingerPrint = "";
string FingerPrintID = "";
```

main.cpp

```
#include "App.h"
#include "Helper.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FingerPrint = Helper().GetFingerPrint();
    FingerPrintID  = Helper().GetFingerPrintID();

    cout<<"FingerPrintID: "<<FingerPrintID<<endl;
    cout<<"FingerPrint: "<<FingerPrint<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

No problem like this.

Can i use global varibles with namespace? If i can, how can i use?

Comment: But the variables are *not* global. At least they are not *declared* as global, they are declared in the `App` namespace. You do not, however, *define* them in the `App` namespace.

Comment: Also, [`using namespace std;` is not good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), especially [in header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575799/using-namespace-std-in-a-header-file).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029272/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-that-could-be-used-in-the-entire-program did i do it wrong?

Comment: Global variables are outside any namespace.

Comment: Continuing from @Someprogrammerdude; this is sometimes known as the "global namespace". Your variables are however "global" in that anything can access them.  You may want to consider your design though - as global variables tend to be the result of bad design.

Comment: i see, can u guys link samples to learn these designs for me, i m very very beginner.

Comment: On a side note, good question; you tried, you did research and then asked posting everything.  If only all new starters did this.

Comment: Thank you sir, i'll do my best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say that you wanted your variables in the app namespace in app.cpp

```
#include "App.h"

using namespace std;

string App::FingerPrint = "";
string App::FingerPrintID = "";
```

should do the job

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thank you for support. I'll accept your answer in 8 mins. :)

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you just declare that somewhere, there are two strings in the namespace `App`. You never actually define those variables.

They don't end up in a namespace simply by being in a file with the same name as a namespace. (`App.cpp` has no relation with `namespace App`, it's just a *convention*).

So you either need to prepend `App::` to your string declarations or wrap them in `namespace App { ... }` somewhere in a `.cpp` file.

That said: Global variables are evil. Try to define them in an `App` or `Config` or `Model` instance instead. During setup, create and initialize the instance and then pass it around as (constructor) parameter.

Comment: @MarijkeBuurlage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list  is a good start